# AJAX not posting Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post edited data using AJAX, but it is posting data only for first line. If i press Enter and write data on second line it is not posting that data.

In short only first line data is getting posted .
Any idea how do I solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: You are missing semicolons after ```var encodedjobMemo = escape(jobMemo)``` and ```var encodedjobTitle = escape(jobTitle)```

Comment: Added, but still not working

Comment: @RS26:any error in console??

Comment: Where do you see that one line? In the browser or on the server? Could it be that you do send the complete content, but somehow you're only printing/displaying that one line?

Comment: While debugging i can see only one that line and also only one line is posted back to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax

```
data: { jobId: jobId, jobTitle:jobTitle , jobMemo: jobMemo, isActive: true }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void CareersUpdateJobPosting()
        {
            JobPosting jobitem = new JobPosting();;
            jobitem.Memo = Request.Form["JobMemo"];
            jobitem.Title = Request.Form["jobTitle"];;
            jobitem.Id = int.Parse(Request.Form["jobId"]);
            jobitem.IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(Form.Request["IsActive"]);

            CareersModel.SaveJobPosting(jobitem);
            Session["JobPosting"]= null;
        }
```

Comment: Then why does function having params?

Comment: I forgot to remove them. Correted. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to debug, but don't know hwy it is going till CareersModel.SaveJobPosting(jobitem);. Any idea??

Comment: Are you sure SaveJobPosting method is working? can you share more details about the problem?

Comment: Ofcourse it is working. It saves the data. My only problem is not all data from div is posted

Answer (score 0):

post data object incorrect, change

```
data: "{ jobId: '" + jobId + "', jobTitle: '" + jobTitle + "', jobMemo: '" + jobMemo + "', isActive: true }"
```

TO

```
data: { jobId: jobId, jobTitle:jobTitle , jobMemo: jobMemo, isActive: true }
```

Comment: Not working.. :( And it is posting first line data, so i don't guess post data object is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Server,

```
public void CareersUpdateJobPosting(JobPosting jobitem)
{
    CareersModel.SaveJobPosting(jobitem);
    Session["JobPosting"]= null;
}
```

Client

```
data: { id:jobId, title:jobTitle, memo:jobMemo, isActive:true }
```

Comment: can you try changing property name at client side, I mean same property name as in JobPosting